# How to draw grid lines in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've  drawn multiple 3d cubes objects using following function:

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertexCount);
```

Now, I have to draw gridline too on it.So can you please tell me how to draw these gridlines(boxes) on it using opengl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to draw lines? 
If so, all you have to do is create vertices as usual and draw them using `GL10.GL_LINES` instead of `GL10.GL_TRIANGLES` (or triangle_strip).
You can change the width of the lines by calling `glLineWidth()`